# Launching hyperlink from DataGridViewLinkCell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, datagridviewlinkcolumn

I'm loading a `DataSet` into a `DataGridView`. The data is a `hyperlink` to a file on the local network but I can't get the link to actually launch the file. Do I have to go into the `clickevent` and actually launch it from there? Or is there a property I can set on the `DataGridViewLinkCell` to do it without the fuss?

Thanks, code is below.

```
'dgMain is the DataGridView
dgMain.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables(0)

'Just an example, will format entire column when I'm done
dgMain(10, 1) = New DataGridViewLinkCell
```

If I did go `clickevent` route I think it would be something like this but it doesn't work very well but I haven't tried much yet:

```
Private Sub dgMain_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgMain.CellContentClick
    If e.RowIndex = -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If dgMain.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewLinkCell Then
        Process.Start(dgMain.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to handle the click event and launch the URL in code (`Process.Start`)

Comment: Wow. Really?. So what's the point of having `DataGridViewLinkCell` in the first place?! Is it just make it blue and underlined?  Because obviously I could call `Process.Start` from the click event of **any** cell type.

Comment: Yes, it is just to have the blue color and underline for the contents, that then changes colour after it is clicked :-P 
On the plus side, you can do anything you want after the click - load a new form, update a WebBrowser control, etc.